# Remote avatars for users/rooms not loading after migrating Synapse

Tags: matrix-synapse

Migrated perthchat.org recently and i've run into the same bug where remote user/room avatars stop loading completely. So i figured okay i'll just purge the remote media until the future again:

`curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer long-access-token" '172.18.0.5:8008/_synapse/admin/v1/purge_media_cache?before_ts=1626710400'`

Strangely this hasn't resolved the issue :P none of the remote avatars want to load. Also going this media purge hasn't freed up any space either, here's the before:

```
    "msg": [
        "381M\t/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_content",
        "5.3G\t/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_thumbnail"
    ]
```

and the after:

```
    "msg": [
        "381M\t/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_content",
        "5.3G\t/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_thumbnail"
    ]
```

Should also note the backup before this migration only copied over the `/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_thumbnail` folder, not the `/matrix/synapse/storage/media-store/remote_content` folder.

**Anyone know anything else i can try to get remote user/room avatars loading again?**

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this was to purge the remote media to a future date, don't forget the epoche time should be in milliseconds, not seconds!

```
# Example:
# $ date --date '149 days ago' +%s
# 1589442217
# $ curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" 'https://matrix.perthchat.org/_synapse/admin/v1/purge_media_cache?before_ts=1589442217000'
```